# why this code is only printing the first statement as output

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, backend, eventemitter

```js
var events = require('events')
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

var fn1 = function() {
  console.log("first fn executed on triggering first event  ")
  eventEmitter.emit('fn1')
}
eventEmitter.on("event1", fn1)
eventEmitter.emit('event1')
eventEmitter.on('fn1', function() {
  console.log("This is the fn triggered on 2nd event")
})
```

output on executing it by  node event1.js is
" first fn executed on triggering first event "

Comment: Probably because the event for `fn1` isn't hooked up until after the event has fired?

Comment: I thought after eventEmitter.emit, the flow of execution then will goes to check on eventEmitter.on('fn1', function(){}  ) and execute it. But we have to specify it before triggering the event, right ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because the handler is registered after the event is fired. Try this:

```
var events = require('events')
var eventEmitter = new events.EventEmitter();

var fn1 = function() {
    console.log("first fn executed on triggering first event  ")
    eventEmitter.emit('fn1')
}
eventEmitter.on("event1", fn1)

eventEmitter.on('fn1', function() {
    console.log("This is the fn triggered on 2nd event")
})
eventEmitter.emit('event1')
```